# Instagram HTTPS User Profile

Tags: ssl, instagram

I'm working on a Facebook application. 
I want to display instagram user profile photos. 
So I need HTTPS URLs...

And i'va find only this : 
http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_183641024_75sq_1372016363.jpg
Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use their S3 bucket - distillery.  It's not part of CDN but it will give a valid SSL functions

https://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_183641024_75sq_1372016363.jpg

Comment: Haven't found a rewrite rule for `https://photos-h.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xpa1/10520134_517353661726271_469805457_a.jpg` Any ideas?